# How to split JSON row data into multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-wrangling

I'm trying to find a way to split (flatten) JSON row data into multiple columns in pandas.

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

[Current Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v3RL.png)

This is an example of what a row looks like:

[Row example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXL0t.png)

I'm able to use the json_normalize function on a single row to achieve the following: (It's just shortened as an example)

[Code Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc7tV.png)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr2tg.png)

However, when trying to apply the normalize function to the whole dataframe, I get 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Are there any suggestions for how to go about doing this? Thanks

I apologise for the use of images, but I kept getting a message saying code is not formatted properly

Comment: Do you want nested keys in json to be a seperate column?

Comment: Yes I'd like each key in a different column like in the photo in 'table' but it has to be applied to the whole datafram and not just a row

Comment: what about converted volume?

Comment: It's fine for now, your answer below was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it's a flat json then you can try :-

`new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['tickers'].tolist())`

The Dataframe constructor takes in a list of dictionary objects and turns the key into columns as default orientation, this is the simplest way if your data is standardized and doesn't have a complex nested structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
all_data_jsons = df['tickers'].to_list()
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data_jsons)
```

Maybe you can try this once